# Percorrer datas imprimindo um campo para cada uma

Tags: php, foreach

Estou fazendo um sistema meio que parecido com um calendário / agenda. Nele tenho uma tabela `semestre` que tem um campo `data de incio` e um de `data fim` e estou precisando percorrer essas datas imprimindo o nome de cada dia no `head` de uma tabela e um botão para cada um desses dias para que o usuário possa cadastrar ou não uma nova entrada naquele dia.

Como percorrer esses dias? Já tentei `foreach` mas não deu certo, tentei também uma lógica com um `for` e não consegui...

Segue um pouco do código que fiz até agora:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)) {
   session_start();
} 

$idSemestre = $_SESSION['SemestreGeral'];

$oSemestre = new semestresclass();
$oSemestre -> listarEdicao($idSemestre);  

$array = mysql_fetch_array($oSemestre->retorno());

$start_date = $array['DataDeInicio'];
$end_date = $array['DataDeTermino'];

$dataInicio = strtotime($start_date);
$dataFim = strtotime($end_date);

foreach ?????????????????????
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A partir do php5.3 existe a classe [DatePeriod](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) quer permite a manipução entre períodos de datas. Basta informar a data de inicio, fim e o perído que será modificado no caso `P1D`(um dia) Outros valores disponiveis são:

```
Y   Anos
M   Meses
D   Dias
W   Semanas
H   Horas
M   Minutos
S   Segundos
```

[**Exemplo**](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/z4t5-riha)

```
<?php

$inicio = new DateTime('2014-10-26');
$fim = new DateTime('2014-10-31');
$fim->modify('+1 day');

$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$periodo = new DatePeriod($inicio, $interval ,$fim);

foreach($periodo as $data){
    echo $data->format("l") . ' | '.$data->format("d/m/Y"). '<br>';

}
```

Comment: Muito fera, era isso mesmo rapaziada!!! Agora saca só, eu precisava tbm era limitar esses dias pra aparecer uma semana e depois pular pra outra... Algum de vcs teria uma ideia de como fazer isso tbm?

Comment: @Alceu como assim? Se for o caso, crie uma pergunta especificamente para esse caso :)

Answer (score 3):

Crie um objeto do tipo `\DatePeriod` passando como parâmetros a data inicial e a final, além de um `\DateInterval` do tipo "P1D", ou seja, um período de um dia entre as datas.

Seu código ficaria assim:

```
$dataInicio = new \DateTime(strtotime($start_date));
$dataFim    = new \DateTime(strtotime($end_date));
$periodo    = new \DatePeriod($dataInicio, new \DateInterval("P1D"), $dataFim);

foreach ($periodo as $data) {
    echo $data->format('d/m/Y');
}
```