# Imprimir próximos dias depois do dia 18/01/2016

Tags: php, data

Tenho que fazer um código onde eu coloco uma data e preciso saber quais são os próximos 5 dias. Por exemplo, hoje é dia **18/01/2016** os próximos dias são **19/01/2016, 20/01/2016, 21/01/2016, 22/01/2016 e 23/01/2016**. Preciso pegar os próximos 5 dias de uma determinada data. Como posso fazer isso ?

Comment: [Percorrer datas imprimindo um campo para cada uma](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38154/91)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$today = getdate(); // pega data de hoje

$raw = "{$today['yday']}. {$today['mon']}. {$today['year']}"; // string da data

$start = DateTime::createFromFormat('d. m. Y', $raw); //formata a data

echo "Data Inicial: " . $start->format('d/m/Y') . "\n"; // exibe data inicial

// cria uma cópia de $start e adiciona 6 dias, pois contamos com hoje
$end = clone $start;
$end->add(new DateInterval('P6D'));


$periodInterval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('tomorrow'); // pega todos os "amanhãs"
$periodIterator = new DatePeriod($start, $periodInterval, $end, DatePeriod::EXCLUDE_START_DATE); // cria período excluindo data inicial

foreach($periodIterator as $date) {
    //mostra cada data no período
    echo "<br>".$date->format('d/m/Y') . " ";
}
```

Saiba mais em: [PHP: Do Jeito Certo](http://br.phptherightway.com/#data_e_horario)

Answer (score 1):

Olá, isso deve resolver:

```
for ($i=1; $i <= 5; $i++) { 
    $proximosDias[] = date('d/m/Y', strtotime(" +$i day"));
}
```

O resultado disso será:

```
array(5) {
[0]=>
string(10) "19/01/2016"
[1]=>
string(10) "20/01/2016"
[2]=>
string(10) "21/01/2016"
[3]=>
string(10) "22/01/2016"
[4]=>
string(10) "23/01/2016"
}
```

O php por não vem com o horário brasileiro, para que arrume isso use está função `date_default_timezone_set("America/Sao_Paulo")`