# Problemas ao gerar horários dinamicamente

Tags: php

Estou utilizando o seguinte script para gerar horas dinamicamente entre um Valor Inicial e um Valor Final com um intervalo de tempo.

Por exemplo: Das 8:00 da manhã até as 15:30, com um intervalo de 15 minutos entre os horários.

Código:

```
<?php
$start = '08:00';
$end = '15:30';

$st = explode(':', $start);
$ed = explode(':', $end);

for($hour = $st[0]; $hour <= $ed[0]; $hour++)
{
    for($min = $st[1]; $min < 60; $min += 15)
    {
        if($ed[1] >= $min and $hour <= $ed[0])
            echo "Hour: {$hour}:{$min}<br/>";
    }
}
```

Porém se eu colocar 15:00 como valor final, o código não me gera as horas com minutos, apenas as horas completas. Preciso que ele gere os minutos mesmo quando for uma hora completa definida como Valor Final, como por exemplo 15:00.

OBS: O script precisa ser com for de maneira semelhante ao exemplo, qualquer outra solução que siga uma estrutura diferente não consigo utilizar em meu código final.

Comment: Na verdade ele gera de 15 em 15 somente até o colocado... se por 30 só até 30... se por 15 só até 15... se por 45 vai até 45... Isso está correto ?

Comment: Então a lógica é essa. Se eu colocar 15 ele tem que gerar - 08:00 - 08:15 - 08:30 e assim por diante. 

O problema é que se eu coloca uma hora final 15:00 em vez de 15:30 como está no exemplo, ele não me gera os horários com minutos. Somente as horas 08:00 - 09:00 e assim por diante até a hora final.

Comment: Sempre tem que ter :15, :30, :45 ?

Comment: Essa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38163/91) resolve? no caso seu intervalo será `PT15M`

Comment: @RBZ Sim sempre tem que ter, se eu definir uma hora final sem os minutos, no caso uma hora completa 15:00 ou 14:00 o script não funciona corretamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Variáveis recebidas
$inicio = '08:15';
$fim = '12:30';

// Quebra horas de minutos
$t1 = explode(':', $inicio);
$t2 = explode(':', $fim);

// Converte para minutos
$min_i = ($t1[0] * 60 + $t1[1]);
$min_f = ($t2[0] * 60 + $t2[1]);

// Define o formato
$formato = '%02d:%02d';

// Loop para impressão
for ($i = $min_i; $i <= $min_f; $i += 15) {

    // Transforma de minutos para horas
    $horas = floor($i / 60);
    // Divide os minutos e tras o resto
    $minutos = ($i % 60);

    // Imprime
    echo 'Hora: ' . sprintf($formato, $horas, $minutos);
    echo "<br>";    
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado @RBZ essa sua solução deu certo. Com ela consigo gerar os horários sem gerar problemas nas demais funções atreladas.

Answer (score 1):

Faça desta forma

Converti primeiro para minutos, para facilitar o processo.

```
$start = self::horasToMinutes('08:00');
    $end = self::horasToMinutes('15:30');
    $dif = $end - $start;
    for($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i += 15){
        echo "Hora:".self::convertToHoursMins($i);
        echo "<br>";
    }


function horasToMinutes($horas){
    $time    = explode(':', $horas);
    $minutes = ($time[0] * 60.0 + $time[1] * 1.0);
    return $minutes;
}

function convertToHoursMins($time, $format = '%02d:%02d') {
    if ($time < 1) {
        return;
    }
    $hours = floor($time / 60);
    $minutes = ($time % 60);
    return sprintf($format, $hours, $minutes);
}
```

Comment: Por que os `.0` em `$minutes = ($time[0] * 60 + $time[1] * 1);` se funciona também sem ?

Comment: Caro amigo a sua solução até funcionou, porém eu preciso que a estrutura seja com um for igual fiz no exemplo pois eu preciso utilizar essa geração de horários integrada a outros serviços que também são dinâmicos e dessa forma proposta não consigo fazer a utilização da maneira que preciso.

Comment: Só pode por `for` ?

Comment: @RBZ Infelizmente sim, precisa ser feito da maneira mais simples possível, assim como cheguei perto de um resultado com o script de exemplo. Se não for algo daquela forma algumas outras funcionalidades ligadas ao horário deixa de funcionar.

Comment: Postei na resposta.

Comment: @JoãoVictor Necessita dos dois `for` para a sua solução funcionar?

Comment: @RicardoRosa A solução proposta pelo RBZ já me atendeu, com um for apenas já resolvia. A questão é que o código precisava ser o mais simples pois eu utilizo essa geração com outras funcionalidades dinâmicas.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode retornar um array com os valores do intervalo. E depois criar uma função que gere os resultados. Assim você pode manipular esses valores em outras funções mais facilmente. Exemplo:

```
function add_interval_to($start , $end , $interval){

      /**
     * Obtém um array com horários calculados apartir de um intervalo 
     * entre horas sendo acrescidos `$interval` minutos.
     * definidos.  
     * 
     * @param string $start
     * @param string $end
     * @param int $interval  *somente minutos
     * @return array
     * 
     */

    $n = 0;  
    for($s = 0 ; $s == $n ; $s++){
        $time    = '+ ' . $interval*$n . ' minute';            
        $times[$s]  = date('H:i:s', strtotime( $time  , strtotime($start)));

        if($times[$s] > $end){
            array_pop($times);
            break;
        }

        $n++;
    }

    return $times;
}

function print_intervals($intervals){
    foreach($intervals as $value){
        echo 'Hora: ' . $value . '</br>'; 
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
var_dump(add_interval_to('08:00:00', '15:30:00'  , 15));
echo '</pre>';

//OU

echo '<pre>';
print_intervals(add_interval_to('08:00:00', '15:30:00'  , 15));
echo '</pre>';
```