# Somatório de horas superior a 24h

Tags: php, soma

Tenho uma variável com o valor '18:00', que corresponde a uma duração recebida através de cálculos entre dois tempos.

```
$tempo = '18:00'; // queria somar 8:00
```

Resposta:

```
$temposomado = '2:00';
```

Valor pretendido:

```
$temposomado = '26:00'
```

Como posso obter este segundo resultado em PHP?

Comment: Provavelmente ele está considerando como horas, acredito que para somar os minutos você deve fazer:
$tempo = '00:18';
Para que ele considere os minutos

Comment: isso esta como string ainda.

Comment: São horas... imaginem 18:00:00. Também pode ser...

Comment: O PHP tem o objeto DateTime para trabalhar com tempo. Tu já chegou a ver algo sobre?

Comment: sim cheguei a ver @gmsantos, mas para já, esta era a melhor hipótese para o caso que estou a desenvolver.

Comment: Amigo, acho que vc deveria considerar uma das respostas correta. Acredito que, ou a do "I like trains" ou a do Isac. Na minha opiniao sao as melhores. Abraço!

Comment: Já coloquei a resposta correcta :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apesar de as outras respostas estarem certas, elas não estão somando os segundos. Então resolvi criar uma alternativa.

Fiz essa resposta basedo **[nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/75993/15361)** e **[nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/291271/1536)**

```
$tempo_inicial= "18:59:59";
 $tempo_somado= "07:00:01";

 sscanf($tempo_inicial, "%d:%d:%d", $horas_inicial, $minutos_inicial, $segundos_inicial);
 sscanf($tempo_somado, "%d:%d:%d", $horas_somado, $minutos_somado, $segundos_somado);

 $tempo_segundos_inicial = $horas_inicial * 3600 + $minutos_inicial * 60 + (isset($segundos_inicial) ? $segundos_inicial : 0);
 $tempo_segundos_somado = $horas_somado * 3600 + $minutos_somado * 60 + (isset($segundos_somado) ? $segundos_somado : 0);
 $total = $tempo_segundos_inicial + $tempo_segundos_somado;

 $horas = floor($total / 3600);
 $minutos = floor(($total - ($horas * 3600)) / 60);
 $segundos = floor($total % 60);

 $temposomado = sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $horas, $minutos, $segundos);

 echo $temposomado; // saída será 26:00:00
```

Veja funcionando no **[ideone](https://ideone.com/XX6E0Z)**

Então, uma versão minha da função `AddPlayTime` da resposta do @WictorChaves baseado no exemplo acima seria assim:

```
$times = array();

$times[] = "18:59:59";
$times[] = "07:00";
$times[] = "00:00:01";

echo AddPlayTime2($times);

function AddPlayTime2($times) {
    $total = 0;
    foreach ($times as $time) {
        if(substr_count($time, ":") == 1)
            $time .= ":00";
        sscanf($time, "%02d:%02d:%02d", $hour, $minute, $second);
        $total += $hour * 3600 + $minute * 60 + $second;
    }

    $horas = floor($total / 3600);
    $minutos = floor(($total - ($horas * 3600)) / 60);
    $segundos = floor($total % 60);

    return sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $horas, $minutos, $segundos);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Bem, primeiro você pode pegar só nas horas e minutos, depois somar

```
$tempo="18:40";
$tempo2="08:30";

$minutos1=substr($tempo, 3, 2);
$minutos2=substr($tempo2, 3, 2);
$soma_min=(int)$minutos2+(int)$minutos1;
if($soma_min > 60){
   $hora_mais=1;
   $soma_min=$soma_min-60;
}else{
   $hora_mais=0;
}
if($soma_min<10){
    $soma_min=$soma_min."0";
}
$hora1 = substr($tempo, 0, 2);
$hora2 = substr($tempo2, 0, 2);

$hora_somada= (int)$hora2+(int)$hora1+$hora_mais;
$tudo_junto=$hora_somada.":".$soma_min;
echo $tudo_junto;
```

Answer (score 5):

Você consegue fazer isso com esta função:

```
AddPlayTime($times);
```

Um exemplo:

```
$times = array();

$times[] = "18:00";
$times[] = "8:00";

echo AddPlayTime($times);

function AddPlayTime($times) {
    $minutes = 0; 
    foreach ($times as $time) {
        list($hour, $minute) = explode(':', $time);
        $minutes += $hour * 60;
        $minutes += $minute;
    }

    $hours = floor($minutes / 60);
    $minutes -= $hours * 60;

    //Aqui ele verifica se passou de 24 hs
    if($hours > 24){
        $vezes = $hours / 24;
        $hours = $hours - (24*intval($vezes));
    }
    return sprintf('%02d:%02d', $hours, $minutes);
}
```

Você cria um array com os horários que você quer somar e envia para função.

**UPDATE**

Eu interpretei a pergunta de outra forma, mas segundo o Andrei Coelho ele precisa da soma dos termos, então é só remover o if, como neste exemplo:

```
$times = array();

$times[] = "18:00";
$times[] = "8:00";

echo AddPlayTime($times);

function AddPlayTime($times) {
    $minutes = 0; 
    foreach ($times as $time) {
        list($hour, $minute) = explode(':', $time);
        $minutes += $hour * 60;
        $minutes += $minute;
    }

    $hours = floor($minutes / 60);
    $minutes -= $hours * 60;

    return sprintf('%02d:%02d', $hours, $minutes);
}
```

Baseado em: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22681725/how-to-sum-n-number-of-time-hhmm-format

Comment: Apesar de eu ter dado +1 a sua publicação não está respondendo. A sua publicação retorna 2h. Ele quer justamente a soma de tempo. No caso 26h

Comment: Fiz uma alteração, desta forma atende das duas maneiras

Answer (score 5):

Já tem várias opções à sua escolha, mas opto por dar também o meu contributo com uma ligeiramente diferente, ainda que parecida à do @AndreiCoelho. Assim como a dele, também a minha implementação tem em consideração segundos.

Implementação:

```
function obterSegundos($tempo){
    $tempos = explode(":", $tempo);
    $horasmins = (int)$tempos[0] * 3600 + (int)$tempos[1] * 60;
    return count($tempos) === 2 ? $horasmins : $horasmins + (int)$tempos[2];
}

function formatarSegundos($total){
    $horas = floor($total / 3600);
    $minutos = floor(($total - $horas * 3600) / 60);
    $segundos = $total % 60;
    return $segundos ? 
        sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $horas, $minutos, $segundos):
        sprintf('%02d:%02d', $horas, $minutos);
}

$t1 = "18:00";
$t2 = "08:30:09";
$total = obterSegundos($t1) + obterSegundos($t2);
$t3 = formatarSegundos($total); //26:30:09
```

[Veja a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/CdWoia)

Testes:

```
$t1 = "11:05";
$t2 = "05:35";
$t3 = formatarSegundos(obterSegundos($t1) + obterSegundos($t2)); //16:40

$t1 = "18:00:59";
$t2 = "08:00:55";
$t3 = formatarSegundos(obterSegundos($t1) + obterSegundos($t2)); //26:01:54

$t1 = "12:00:05";
$t2 = "01:30";
$t3 = formatarSegundos(obterSegundos($t1) + obterSegundos($t2)); //13:30:05

$t1 = "11:55";
$t2 = "01:56";
$t3 = formatarSegundos(obterSegundos($t1) + obterSegundos($t2)); //13:51

$t1 = "1:05";
$t2 = "2:10";
$t3 = formatarSegundos(obterSegundos($t1) + obterSegundos($t2)); //03:15
```

Comment: Muito boa sua função `obterSegundos()`

Comment: Se ele escolher apenas por performance, ele irá escolher a do "I Like Trains", mas se ele for escolher performance e o parâmetro de  segundos ele teria que escolher a sua. Veja: https://ideone.com/PyMIV5

Comment: @AndreiCoelho Interessante esse ideone que você montou :). No fim do dia a minha é bem parecida à sua, diria mesmo quase uma variante.

Comment: a dos segundos não me interessa tanto, pois só tratamos horas e minutos.

Comment: @White Funciona em ambos os casos, logo não tem risco de quebrar, se mais tarde se quiserem interpretar também os segundos. E também não força a ter 2 digitos em cada parte.

Answer (score 4):

Uma forma que considero simples:

```
// Variáveis recebidas
$hora1 = '09:15';
$hora2 = '19:30';

// Quebra horas de minutos
$t1 = explode(':', $hora1);
$t2 = explode(':', $hora2);

// Converte para minutos e soma
$min_1 = ($t1[0] * 60 + $t1[1]);
$min_2 = ($t2[0] * 60 + $t2[1]);
$min_t = $min_1 + $min_2;

// Define o formato
$formato = '%02d:%02d';

// Converte os minutos para horas e minutos
$horas = floor($min_t / 60);
$minutos = ($min_t % 60);

// Imprime
echo 'Hora: ' . sprintf($formato, $horas, $minutos);
```

Aqui uso o mesmo script para imprimir intervalos:

[Problemas ao gerar horários dinamicamente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/289129/92908)

Comment: agradeço, mas esta resposta continua-me a dar horas não superiores a 24.

Comment: Estranho, pois testei aqui, testei agora no http://phptester.net/, e está normal. Precisa ver como está imprimindo, se não está alterando alguma propriedade.