# Pegar data dos próximos 12 meses com php

Tags: php

Boa noite gente, como eu posso fazer, para pegar o 1° dia de cada mês, contando como inicio a data de hoje, e pegando o proximo dia 01/08/2018 e os próximos 12 meses.

Tente esse código:

```
$firstDayNextMonth = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first day of next month'));
```

Como seria pra pegar os 12 próximos?

Comment: Você leu a documentação da função `strtotime` para ver se algo lhe atendia?

Comment: Se é o primeiro dia, não seria mais fácil enumerar, já que é sempre dia "1", então seria um loop simples. Ou você quer o primeiro dia da semana?

Comment: Acredito que a lógica seja a mesma dessas duas perguntas: [Como criar uma lista de datas do ano em php, pulando os finais de semana?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111656/91) e [Percorrer datas imprimindo um campo para cada uma](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38154/91)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Com DateTime

Se usar `DateTime` para pegar um mês por vez em um loop eu usar `::modify()` pode extrair, por exemplo:

```
<?php

$dt = new DateTime('first day of next month');

$datas = array( $dt->format('Y-m-d') );

for ($i = 0; $i < 12; $i++) {
    $dt->modify('+1 month');

    $datas[] = $dt->format('Y-m-d');
}

print_r($datas);
```

Resultado:

> ```
> Array
> (
>     [0] => 2018-08-01
>     [1] => 2018-09-01
>     [2] => 2018-10-01
>     [3] => 2018-11-01
>     [4] => 2018-12-01
>     [5] => 2019-01-01
>     [6] => 2019-02-01
>     [7] => 2019-03-01
>     [8] => 2019-04-01
>     [9] => 2019-05-01
>     [10] => 2019-06-01
>     [11] => 2019-07-01
>     [12] => 2019-08-01
> )
> ```

Isto vai pegar 13 meses na verdade, pois já iniciamos com o primeiro mês, já que você disse:

> e pegando o proximo dia 01/08/2018 e os próximos 12 meses.

Mas se quer pegar a partir do mês proximo contar os 12 meses então altere isto para 11 o `for`:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 11; $i++) {
```

---

### Sem DateTime

Se bem que acho que nem precisaria disto, afinal se é o primeiro dia bastaria "enumerar" com um array somando o mês, quando passar de 12 volta para o mês 1 e soma o ano:

```
<?php

$j = count($meses);
$ano = date('Y');
$mes = date('m');
$datas = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < 12; $i++) {
    $mes++;

    if ($mes > 12) {
       $mes = 1;
       $ano++;
    }

    $datas[] = sprintf('%04d-%02d-01', $ano, $mes);
}

print_r($datas);
```

Comment: Muito bom, ajudou muito. Obrigado.